# What does the operator "=" means in class declaration in Dart?

Tags: dart

In my studies of Dart languages, I found some packaged using this kind of class declaration:

```dart
class _Base = Authentication with Utilities, Validators;
```

I don't understand what the operator `=` is doing here, is it a kind of alias?

Comment: Syntax for creating a class where all its members comes from other classes by using mixin's. You can read more about mixin here: https://medium.com/flutter-community/dart-what-are-mixins-3a72344011f3 . I guess the use of `=` is to make it more clear that it is your intention that you class does not add any other members and is an alternative for `{}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is a shortcut to create inherit classes with mixins.

The example is same to:

```
class _Base extends Authentication with Utilities, Validators{
  _Base(): super(); // or with args
}
```

Utilities and validators are mixins.